# How can I solve the error "page not found(404)" in my 1st django project?

Tags: django

I'm very new to django and I stuck in my first project
the error says   Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/about
using the URLconf defined in emuhay.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
The current path, about, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I'm expecting "Contat page" but page not found displayed every time
my code is below

```
#Url code
    
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Home Page')

def contact(request):
    return HttpResponse('Contact Page')


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',home),
    path('about/',contact),
]



#setting.py

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'yra+iwr3x_)@ssxj)e%h^7=m(te0mh!_4xx61g7j2j4y)o9z&$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'hihi',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'emuhay.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'emuhay.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True




STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Try replacing the order of your `urlpatterns` so that `path('',home)` is last. This should help

Comment: Add your `urls.py`. If not added in your project, add it and check

Answer (score 1):

This part of the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/) would be helpful

Try this in your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('about/', contact, name='contact'),
]
```